# update a table using inner join syntax in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-update, inner-join

i am curious about how updating a table with inner join works.  if i run the following statement:

```
update tbl1 a
inner join tbl2 b using (id)
set a.val = b.val;
```

what happens to the records in `tbl1` that do not have a match in `tbl2`? will they simply not be updated and left as is in `tbl1`? will they be deleted?

i realize i can run this and get the answer but i'm also interested in the mechanics of how this works behind the scenes and was hoping somebody could elucidate this for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The update statement is operating on tbl1.

The join is providing a filter that specifies which rows to update in tbl1.

As an added bonus, the join is also providing a value for the column.

The update statement does not and cannot delete rows from a table.

Comment: i guess what i'm trying to understand is what's happening in the background: what if you did left or right join for example? what would mysql set the values to for rows that have no matches?  i'm trying to understand the mechanics of what is going on in the background.  would it be null, for example, in the left join scenario where `tbl2` does not have a matching row?

Comment: If tbl2 does not have a matching row, then a.val will be set to NULL.

Comment: then how would an update with an inner join vs. a left join be different? it seems they are the same thing here.

Answer (score 1):

**Q:** What happens to the records in `tbl1` that do not have a match in `tbl2`?

**A:** They will not be updated since they have no match from `tbl2`. From the definition, the `INNER JOIN` keyword return rows when there is at least one match in both tables. The only keyword that could delete record from your table is the `DELETE` DML.